# Samba fails externally, works locally

Tags: samba, ubuntu

I have an Ubuntu Server (Hardy LTS) virtual machine, in which im trying to share a folder via samba.

I can list shares *locally* fine, via:

```
smbclient -L localhost
```

But using similar on my host machine, where xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is the Ubuntu IP (OS X):

```
smbclient -L //xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -U myusername
```

I get:

```
Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx at port 139
error connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:139 (Connection refused)
Error connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (Connection refused)
lang_tdb_init: /usr/lib/samba/en_GB.UTF-8.msg: No such file or directory
Connection to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx failed (Error NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_REFUSED)
```

Is this a samba error, or a firewall error?

My smb conf file, is the default, with the following changes:

```
interfaces = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/8 eth0
security = user
username map = /etc/samba/smbusers

[homes]
read only = no
valid users = %S
comment = Home Directories
browseable = yes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it works locally and it's listening on the external interface it's a firewall or routing issue.

Comment: This was the case ... I can confirm that my firewall works ;)

For those reading post at a later date, try iptables --flush to clear your firewall and allow everything in and out.